# Can there be really a theory of everything?

Tags: theory-of-everything

If quantum theory becomes compatible with Einstein's theory of gravity, we get the theory of everything. But if it can predict anything in the universe (provided boundary equations are given) wouldn't it predict itself. I mean won't the theory tell us when the theory will be formed? This sounds quite absurd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three flaws in what you're suggesting :

- A theory of everything need not be deterministic.  Current mainstream thinking would be to expect a non-deterministic theory of everything.
- Even if a deterministic theory was found, you can't use it to deduce when it will be found until after you have it.  And that's ignoring how unrealistically complex such a deduction would be.
- A theory is a *model* for reality.  It simply models the behavior we see around us to some level of accuracy and in some circumstances.  A theory of everything is the ideal theory, but there's no reason to assume we can actually develop such a theory or would ever stop refining it as the accuracy we can measure at increases and reveals more detail than we thought was there.  A theory of everything could be a dragon's tail that we chase forever.

Comment: if boundary equations are given TOE can be deterministic

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to stipulate that a Theory of Everything must be self-reflexive.  In other words, that it allow a "consciousness" of itself, or that it explain itself.  Don't all workable theories do this?

Alternatively, your question may suggest that a Theory of Everything must predict  the time at which it will be developed.  This would be trivial and absurd, as any rationalization can predict the past.

I think you are reading into the long-sought TOE a meaning that is not there.